# How to fix a broken yum install rpcbind package?

Tags: centos, yum

I tried to upgrade rpcbind package but it is failed.

```
yum update rpcbind

Transaction check error:
  package rpcbind-0.2.0-42.el7.x86_64 is already installed
```

So I tried to reinstall the package:

```
yum -d 0 -e 0 -y reinstall rpcbind
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem

Protected multilib versions: rpcbind-0.2.0-42.el7.x86_64 != rpcbind-0.2.0-38.el7.x86_64
```

How to force yum to reinstall the rpcbind package?

Comment: Have you modified your repos after the very first rpcbind installation?

Comment: I haven't. I did Ctrl-C on `yum update` when it is in a middle of the update process. So i think it cause that problem. I also did `yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only` before those command.

Answer (score -1):

Use below command:

```
rpm -Uvh --replacefiles rpcbind-version.rpm
```

Comment: I haven't voted on this answer, but why not make the answer an Answer by providing the actual command that the OP would use? They are working with the `rpcbind` package, not the `package` package.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller updated the command

Comment: Great! We’ll see if it helps the OP.